# Does Ubuntu 22.x work on Dell Poweredge T430?

Tags: server, dell

Does anyone know if 22.x runs on Dell Poweredge T430 with XEON?
I want to upgrade hardware (Dell Optiplex 9020) and just plug my SSD into a new (used) T430.

Thanks for any answer!
Dennis

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 22.x system, and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has various products (server/desktop) which offer various kernel stack options, but you've given no *clear* clues as to system, nor provided an actual *clean problem* (the question) which can be answered except to provide off-topic opinions (*opinions are best on forums, not Q&A sites such as this*).  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask